# Rails Routing Error (undefined local variable or method `micropost_comment')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

> NameError in StaticPages#home
>   I don't quite understand why. Here my code from `views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

```
<% if current_user?(comment.user) %>

   <%= link_to 'Destroy', micropost_comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

<% end %>
```

Here's my routes

```
 micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                       PATCH  /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                       PUT    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                       DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

can some one explain how to fix this error

```
undefined local variable or method `micropost_comment'
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of link_to is a path

micropost_comment is not a path, you should replace it with micropost_comment_path

also regarding to you routes, you should add those params :

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', micropost_comment_path(micropost_id:comment.micropost_id, id:comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

I think you don't need nesting routes though, but it's an other question

Comment: Though, this answer was second by timing. It was the first correct one. The answer from Andrey Deineko initially did not consider nested routes and was edited later.

Comment: Yes i wanted to add the ids things... you can accept this answer and give a +1 to Andrey ;)

Comment: I was just passing by and was about to answer it, but saw that it was taken care of, and decided just to leave a comment about that. And, I have given you my +1, though.

Comment: ah ok sorry i thought you were the author !

Comment: And I was considering to give Andrey -1 actually, because his initial answer was literally "It should be a route helper with path at the end: link_to 'Destroy', micropost_comment_path..." (nothing more) and was wrong. It is not a quality answer. It is a rush to get credits on a simple question.